# ruby update active record

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to update records using this:

```
nn = Npanxx.find(:all, :limit => 1, :order => 'updated desc')
nn.each do |n|
  n.state = 'some state'
  n.city = 'some city'
  n.save
end
```

I am getting an unknown column error.  That Npanxx table doesn't have an `id` column.  Is this the reason it is not working?  If so, how can I work around this.  I also tried:

```
n.update_attributes({:state => 'some state'})
```

This gets the same error.

Comment: Can you give the exact error message?

Comment: can you post the migration that made the table?

Comment: here is the error: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'npanxx.' in 'where clause': UPDATE `npanxx` SET `STATE` = 'NJ' WHERE `npanxx`.`` IS NULL

Comment: the table already existed so i didn't use migration to create it

Comment: Try to print nn[0] before `each`. Does it has id?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just alter the table and add an id column.  Works fine now.